# Group data Set with OrderBy in Sql

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
id   name   amount
1    A      12
2    B      10
3    A      24
4    C      39
5    B      25
6    B      23
7    C      15
```

i want to get data like this

```
id   name   amount
1    A      12
2    A      24
3    B      10
4    B      23
5    B      25
6    C      15
7    C      39
```

i want to get the data like this -- set of A with the ascending amount and the B with the ascending amount and the C
how to do that 
i tried this code but it only return 3 values (i'm using laravel)

```
DB::table('person')             
->groupBy('name')
->orderBy('amount','ASC')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `orderBy()` many time at any query

```
DB::table('person')
->orderBy('amount','ASC')
->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: doesn't work .only return one value of A,B,C .only 3 records

Comment: remove the `groupBy` @sasy

Answer (score 0):

Do not use group by.Use only orderby. First with name than amount. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DB::table('person')->orderBy(array('amount'=>'asc', 'name'=>'asc'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
$persons = DB::table('person')             
->orderBy('amount','asc')
->get();

$result = $persons->groupBy('name');

return $result;
```

I think this works fine.